# How to convert a chain into a number

Tags: numbers

In Apple Numbers I want a cell to have 4x8x7 (or 4*8*7) to show the detail of the volume, and in another cell I want that volume calculated 4*8*7=224 based on the first cell. But it doesn't consider the first cell as an operation. Which formula can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was given this answer on another website:
put =4*8*7 in the first cell, set it to *text* format, duplicate it and set it to *automatic* format so that it calculates the result

Answer (score 1):

You could use the string concatenation operator '&' and make a formula like this:

=B2&" X "&B3&" X "&B4
which would display "4 X 8 X 7"

then have another formula that actually calculates the function:

=B2*B3*B4
which would display "224"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/brAkp.png

Comment: I was working on a convoluted formula with multiple SEARCH and MID functions, then realized this was a far more straightforward approach.

Comment: I would have to fill 3 more cells manually, something I would rather avoid having to do